# Navigation bar influence UITableViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uinavigationbar

I have a UITableViewController connected with a UINavigationController in  my storyboard. when I scroll down my table I can see the rows going to the back side to the "navigation bar".

Making a brief check, I realized that the navigation bar are not influencing the table size (It appears that the navigation bar is in front of my table). Since when I select the table size:

```
-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableViews heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    CGFloat value = tableViews.frame.size.height;

    NSLog(@"Table size -> %f",value);

    return value/2;

}
```

He returns the same size os my window... what I could do to make the "navigation bar" to influence the size of my table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a few options. Try one of the following:

1. Subtract the height of the nav bar and status bar from the table view frame height.

   ```
   CGFloat value = tableViews.frame.size.height - CGRectGetMaxY(self.navigationController.navigationBar.frame);
   ```
2. Don't put the table view behind the navigation bar. Fix this by adding the following line to your table view controller's `viewDidLoad`:

   ```
   self.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdgeLeft | UIRectEdgeRight;
   ```

   This prevents the table view from going under the nav bar or toolbar.

One more note. If you want all rows to have the same height, don't implement the `heightForRowAtIndexPath` method. Instead, simply set the table view's `rowHeight` property.